# How do I get ViewData inside a form to display correctly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata, hidden-field

```
<%:ViewData["galleryId"]%>
<% using (Html.BeginForm(
             "FinishEdit" , 
             "GalleryManager" , 
             FormMethod.Post , 
             new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }
             )
         ) 
   {%>
    <%:Html.Hidden("galleryId" , ViewData["galleryId"])%>
<% } %>
```

The view data outside of the form renders correctly, but the `viewdata` inside the form does not. What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try clearing the model state in your controller action if you intend to modify any of the POSTed variables and render the same view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FinishEdit()
{
    ...
    ModelState.Remove("galleryId");
    ViewData["galleryId"] = "some new gallery id";
    return View();
}
```

Html helpers are first looking in the model state dictionary values before ViewData and Model.

Answer (score 2):

Html.Hidden helper looks first [ModelState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.aspx) dictionary. This could be a reason.